# Creating a webserver in C#, but use Firebase Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, authentication, webapi

We have developed a web service application using WebAPI C#. We want to change our authentication method to Firebase. So our client applications could log in using Firebase authentication, then with that authentication have access to our C# web service.

Are there any libraries developed for this method? I have seen libraries, but they are meant to be used in a c# client application, not in a server-side application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact a well supported scenario. After the user signs in to Firebase Authentication on the client, you'll want to pass their ID token to your web service over a secure connection. Your server can then decode and verify the ID token, and use the information in there to grant the user access to information they're authorized to.

This flow is also described in the Firebase documentation on [verifying an ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), so I recommend checking that out.